# Remove camera set in object

Tags: rendering, objects, 3d-view, camera

When I start to render an image, it is rendered from a plane that I have created. I can easily remove the object and the problem is solved, but **I want to solve the problem from another point of view.**

I want to remove the camera that is set in the object, here it is a plane.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved: I simply deleted the marker by right-clicking and pressing `Del` on the keyboard, then going to the scene properties and setting the camera for the scene.

[image]